# JMS Read Message MalformedInputException

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

I always get an MalformedInputException, when read an Queue-Meassage with JMS.
My code is:

```
Message message = mqMessageConsumer.receiveNoWait();
while (message != null) {
   if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
        String inputTmp = ((TextMessage) message).getText();
[...]
```

I think the Problem is the Message, it starts with Hex-Representation of the length x'02A8', and he can't convert it:

```
.y<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Document xmlns:xsi=...
```

Stacktrace is:

```
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSException: JMSCMQ1049: The character set '1208(UTF-8) Unmappable Action: REPORT, Unmappable Replac
 ement: 63, spaceByte: 32' cannot convert some or all of the string 'ÝB§755cab7'
 An attempt was made to send or receive string data using a character set not capable of translating the strings content.
 Only encode a message using a character set known to be appropriate for the string data being transmitted.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:437)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.j2se.NLSServices.createException(NLSServices.java:319)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.nls.NLSServices.createException(NLSServices.java:226)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.WMQUtils.computeTextFromBytes(WMQUtils.java:382)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.WMQUtils.computeTextFromByteBuffer(WMQUtils.java:421)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.messages.WMQTextMessage.getText(WMQTextMessage.java:240)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsTextMessageImpl.getText(JmsTextMessageImpl.java:205)
    at com.ibm.jms.JMSTextMessage.getText(JMSTextMessage.java:124)
    at myProgramm
 Caused by: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
    at java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(CoderResult.java:292)
    at java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder.decode(CharsetDecoder.java:816)
    at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.system.JmqiCodepage.bytesToString(JmqiCodepage.java:917)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.WMQUtils.computeTextFromBytes(WMQUtils.java:375)
    ... 6 more
```

Is there an option to get the Message as byte[] or without conversion.
Unfortunately, the sender can not change the Message.
Or should i use the MQI Api? 
Thank you very much!
Florian

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead:

```
Message message = mqMessageConsumer.receiveNoWait();
while (message != null) {
   if (message instanceofJMSBytesMessage) {
        String inputTmp = ((JMSBytesMessage)message).readUTF();
[...]
```

[JMS client message conversion and encoding](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q032120_.htm)

Comment: Thanks, but how can I say that the consumer consumes an Byte Message? Now I get com.ibm.jms.JMSTextMessage incompatible with com.ibm.jms.JMSBytesMessage

Comment: The Problem is the MQ Format of the Message, with MQ-String he always decides for JMSTextMessage. If Format is MQ-None he takes ByteMessage. I think, there is no option without changing the Message

Answer (score 0):

I think in my case there is no Solution without changing the Message. To get JMSByteMessage the Message Format musst be MQ-None, with MQ-String you always get an JMSTextMessage. Maybe there is an Way with MQI, but because my Programm is an IMS JMP I'm not allowed to use MQI. I asked the Producer of the Message to change it. Thanks to JoshMC for your Answer